# web.config to allow urls ending with .config

Tags: asp.net, rest, web-config

I have REST url which is like '/api/abc/xyz/pqr.Config'. This is invalid URL as ASP.NET considers this as possible security breach. I used  'alwaysAllowedUrls' tag in web.config but there can be 100's of such kind of URL. So is there a way I can specify RegEx which will allow URLs matching that RegEx. This is not available in  'alwaysAllowedUrls'.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your `<system.webServer>` of web.config, this is dynamic path, every where which you have `pqr.config` file this can be shown to everyone.

```
    <security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <fileExtensions>
          <remove fileExtension=".config" />
          <add fileExtension=".config" allowed="true" />
        </fileExtensions>
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
  <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension="/api/abc/xyz/*.*.config" mimeType="text/xml" />
  </staticContent>
```

Comment: this will allow all urls ending with .config which is bad acc. to security. Correct me if I am wrong. I want to allow url matching RegEx else .net can block url as usual.

Comment: so basically pqr can be anything but '/api/abc/xyz/' is fixed. so url can be
'/api/abc/xyz/ghj.Config'
'/api/abc/xyz/rty.Config' & so on.

Comment: @Ranjit Powar Excuse me, I edit my answer, I test it, it works properly.